# Apply family solution for multiple for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataframe that has multiple variables with one string in it (the `a1, a2, ...an` variables), and I'm trying to determine if the string in the `an` variables appears in the column `string`. Each `an` variable has a corresponding `cn` variable. For example, I want `c1` to contain `Checked` in it if the string in `a1` appears in `string`, and so on. I've developed the below for loop solution for this (some example data at the end of this post) but I was wondering if there was an apply family solution to this that might be quicker and easier to code? In the real data, there are over 100 a and c variables.

```
#For loop solution

for (var in seq(2, 10, 2)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i, var]<-ifelse(grepl(df[i, var-1], df$string[i])=="TRUE", "Checked",  "Unchecked")
  }
}


#### Example data ####
a1<-c("zebra", "giraffe", "elephant")
a2<-c("hyena", "monkey", "antelope")
a3<-c("badger", "deer", "kangaroo")
a4<-c("tiger", "lion", "coyote")
a5<-c("penguin", "bear", "gorilla")

c1<-""
c2<-""
c3<-""
c4<-""
c5<-""

string<-c("elephant/bear/coyote/penguin/monkey",
          "giraffe/antelope/monkey/gorilla/tiger",
          "elephant/antelope/kangaroo/coyote/gorilla")

df<-cbind.data.frame(a1, c1, a2, c2, a3, c3, a4, c4, a5, c5, string, 
stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Generalizable to any number of a's.

```
require(dplyr) # For readability
a<-cbind.data.frame(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, stringsAsFactors=F)

a %>%
  sapply(function(x) {mapply(function(a) grepl(a, string), x) %>% diag}) %>% 
                                     # Check for condition in above line
  ifelse("Checked", "Unchecked") %>% # Convert True and False to Checked and Unchecked
  data.frame %>%                     # Convert to data.frame
  setNames(paste0("c", 1:5))         # Setnames

         c1        c2        c3        c4        c5
1 Unchecked Unchecked Unchecked Unchecked   Checked
2   Checked   Checked Unchecked Unchecked Unchecked
3   Checked   Checked   Checked   Checked   Checked
```

In base R

```
c_column = data.frame(ifelse(sapply(a, function(x) diag(mapply(function(a) grepl(a, string), x))), "Checked", "Unchecked"))
names(c_column) = paste0("c", 1:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking for, using `sapply`

```
df[,2*(1:5)] <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df), 
                   function(i) sapply(2*(1:5)-1, 
                      function(j) c("Unchecked","Checked")[1+grepl(df[i,j], df$string[i])]
                  )))

df
        a1        c1       a2        c2       a3        c3     a4        c4      a5        c5                                    string
1    zebra Unchecked    hyena Unchecked   badger Unchecked  tiger Unchecked penguin   Checked       elephant/bear/coyote/penguin/monkey
2  giraffe   Checked   monkey   Checked     deer Unchecked   lion Unchecked    bear Unchecked     giraffe/antelope/monkey/gorilla/tiger
3 elephant   Checked antelope   Checked kangaroo   Checked coyote   Checked gorilla   Checked elephant/antelope/kangaroo/coyote/gorilla
```